# How to read file header in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write a program in C++ so that I can read a file with a file header that has 3 bytes. 1 byte for 1 variable.

I want to define a struct in C++ with 3 variables and all of them has 1 byte so that I can read value from file to these three variables.

My idea is this:

```
struct header{
    datatype a;
    datatype b;
    datatype c;
}
```

Then I can:

```
FILE *fp=fopen(fileName,"rb");
header head;
fread(&head, sizeof(header),1,fp);
```

Those variables are used for calculating and their range is from 0-255. What datatype I can use in c++?

Comment: I wouldn't normally downvote for this question, but you're asking "what datatype in C++ is 1 byte". That's proof that there was no research done here.

Comment: I know char has size 1 byte, but I need calculating. I mean when I do : `char a = 10; a += 1; cout << a;` That is not what I want. And I am not sure what to do.

Comment: `char` has size 1 _on most platforms_. Don't rely on it. Also, `char` is an integral type. You can use it to make calculations. Just cast it before printing: `cout << (int)a;`.

Comment: Also, this other question may be relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing

Answer (score 4):

Use [`uint8_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) included in `<cstdint>` for `datatype` which has 1 byte length.

Comment: But the bits read will be exactly the same, and how the compiler treats it could be irrelevant if the OP wants to read them individually for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `char`, that's exactly 1 byte.